# How to set maxlength for <s:textarea> tag in Struts2?

Tags: struts2

I am developing an application using Struts2 and jquery and would like to set maxlength for struts2 s:textarea tag. Unlike Struts2 s:textfield, the s:textarea tag does not seem to be supporting maxlength attribute. Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *does not seem to be supporting maxlength attribute*? Did you try it, how?

Comment: is it ok to use jquery ? or plain javascript ?

Answer (score 4):

Use it, this must work:-

```
<s:textarea name="someName" maxlength="100" class="form-control" rows="5"></s:textarea>
```

**maxlength works with textarea in struts2**

here, rows indicates default height of textarea i.e equal to 5 rows. if characters are more, it shows vertical-scroll bar on it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `<s:textarea/>` is one of those Struts UI Tags [that allow dynamic attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21256672/1654265), your problem turns into:

> How to set `maxlength` for `<textarea>` tag in HTML?

And the solution is: use Javascript, checking the length during key / mouse events.

You can find a [kick off example here](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<s:textfield maxlength="300">
</s:textfield>
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh.  My question was about setting maxlength for struts2 tag textarea <s:textarea>

Answer (score 0):

Okay. When you want to set the size of the `textarea` in struts2 follow bellow patter it may work

```
  <s:textarea  cols="5" rows="6"></s:textarea>
```

define size of it as you wish.